# Why is there no support for CDMA in Android NeighboringCellInfo?

Tags: android, cdma

Does anyone know why there is no support for NeighboringCellInfo for CDMA in Android SDK?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/NeighboringCellInfo.html

The documentation only mentions: 
    TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS 
    TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE 
    TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS 
    TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA 
    TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA 
    TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA

Could anyone explain if there is a technical reason for not providing NeighboringCellInfo for CDMA?

Are neighboring cells irrelevant for CDMA?

Comment: Close cousin of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484888/neighboringcellinfo-on-cdma-phone, although it won't help you much, since there's no answers posted.  I get the distinct impression that `getNeighboringCellInfo()` is either unreliable, or people don't know how to use it.  At least [one source](http://www.krvarma.com/2010/06/using-android-telephonymanager/) states that the neighboring cell info isn't even available until just before the cell phone decides to hand off to another cell tower (comment at bottom of page), and the rest of the time the function will return null.

Comment: My guess is that the PhoneStateListener is there to tell you when the neighboring cell info can be read. And it still doesn't explain why the function is missing for CDMA while it exists for all other modes.

Comment: Which is why I posted a comment instead of an answer.